# passing url to iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have links on the side of my page such as "home", "news", "contacts", ... and an iframe in the middle of the page, I would like the iframe to go to diffrent urls according to the link selected.
Could I do this by only using html and/or how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the iframe a name attribute, like this:

```
<iframe name='content' ...>
```

and then give each link a corresponding target attribute, like this:

```
<a href='news.html' target='content' ...>
```

Comment: @Jonathan: Ah, all those years at secretarial college are paying off!